# Mongo object has no method 'sort'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api

```
Accounts = new Mongo.Collection('accounts');
```

(Declaration of Accounts)

```
var accountPhone = {'phoneNum': phoneNum};
if (Accounts.find(accountPhone).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1)) {
```

(Line that is making the error, called on a POST call)

When I make the post call I get this

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sort'
    at Object.Api.addRoute.post.action (okey-api2.js:98:51)
    at Route.Route._callEndpoint (packages/nimble_restivus/packages/nimble_restivus.js:318:1)
    at packages/nimble_restivus/packages/nimble_restivus.js:209:1
    at packages/simple_json-routes/packages/simple_json-routes.js:53:1
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know which library/driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). If so, try `sort` and `limit` options:

```
Accounts.find(accountPhone, {
    sort: {
        $natural: -1
    },

    limit: 1
})
```

Link to [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find).

Comment: I hate meteor. "Lets redefine the API great idea!"